# Excel Convert the correct Date type

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently following the date type dd/mm/yyyy i need to have another row showing the month in mmm type. E.g. From 13/09/2014 to SEP

My formula is =Text(A2, "mmm") which is the correct formula,

However it reads the text as mm/dd/yyyy thus having an error. How do I tell the excel to read it in dd/mm/yyyy format.

The format of the dd/mm/yyyy field is General - No specific format

Comment: If TEXT function returns the same value you have in A2 then that means A2 is formatted as text. Is dd/mm/yyyy the default format for your region? If so you can convert to true dates using text to columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to apply for just this Excel formula, Overmind's answer covers how. If you want it to apply always to everything, you have to change the system's date format.

Note that this will change every date displayed that uses system settings as well as changing how you must type in dates. For instance, if you change the system short date format to `d/M/yyyy` and then type `9/13` into Excel, it'll assume you meant September 1, 2013, because `13` doesn't make sense as a month so it must be a year and that means that `9` must be the month.

Here are the screenshots showing how to change the system's time format on Windows 7.

Right-click on the time in the system tray and click `Adjust date/time`

[image: Screenshot 1]

Click on `Change date and time...`

[image: Screenshot 2]

Click on `Change calendar settings`

[image: Screenshot 3]

Change the format as desired and click `OK`

[image: Screenshot 4]

Answer (score 0):

Any format to any format can be converted with some cell function manipulations.
Example: YYYYMMDD to mm/dd/yyyy.

```
=DATE(LEFT(D1,4),MID(D1,5,2),RIGHT(D1,2))
```

For your scenario, il will look like:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(D1,4),MID(D1,4,2),LEFT(D1,2))
```

The method is very straight-forward.

P.S. there is a changeable format. Right Click on the row and click on Format cells. Under the Number tab, click on Custom. There you can set it to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your formula, it works, however is there a setting i can change instead to read it as dd/mm/yyyy some sort of global settings, if not I'll have to keep doing this every single time i need to convert.